# How do I add a section to a wordpress home template

Tags: php, wordpress, layout

I could really use some help with this one... I managed to add a lead section to my wp homepage (home.php):

```
<?php

if (is_home() && $paged < 2 ) {
get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'news');

} else {

if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  get_template_part('template-parts/content');
endwhile;

else :

get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none');

endif;

} ?>
```

Now there is 1 lead article at the top of the page (< 2) and the rest after that. What I would like to do now is adding a section in between those. Kinda like (> 2 but < 5). The content-news template looks like this:

```
<?php /* Display Posts */
if (have_posts()) :
$counter = 1;
$max_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if ($counter == 1) :
        get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'lead'); ?>
        <?php
    else :
        get_template_part('template-parts/content');
    endif;
    $counter++;
endwhile;

else :

get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none');

endif;
?>
```

There are basically two sections now, I want it to be 3 if you know what I mean? I don't know how to explain it better...